# Sublime text disappearing on ubuntu subsytem for windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, sublimetext3

I have an ubuntu subsystem for windows (i think thats what its called where i can run commands through ubuntu terminal in my windows pc to open sublime or anything, no virtual machine needed). But i've been facing a problem, after some period of inactivity my already open sublime text disappears and then i can't get it back after running the subl/sublime command unless i restart my pc and do it all over again. How to fix this?

It works when i restart my pc, but its tedious to do it always

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you see it running in `ps` but not visible? If so, something to try when this happens: run some different GUI application that is not already running (e.g. `xterm` or `glxgears`) ; does that cause the existing windows to become active? I have seen this problem in a variety of GUI applications in WSL (including but not limited to Sublime) and it appears to be related to the connection between WSL and its window manager being broken; establishing a new connection fixes it.